# Filterpipe on Angular Template where Object Value describes content

Tags: angular, templates, pipe, key

I have a Object Mockup:

```
       export const IMAGES: Image[] = [
            {
                ID: 1,
                NAME: 'Werk1',
                YEAR: 1992,
                IMGURL: 'assets/Images/1/img1.jpg',
                MATERIAL: 'Collage auf Leinwand',
                SIZE: '11cm x 12.4cm',
                SERIE: 'BG-SWIPER'
            },
            {
                ID: 2,
                NAME: 'Werk2',
                YEAR: 1992,
                IMGURL: 'assets/Images/1/img2.jpg',
                MATERIAL: 'Collage auf Leinwand',
                SIZE: '12.25cm x 19.85cm',
                SERIE: 'BG-SWIPER'
            },
            {
                ID: 3,
                NAME: 'Werk3',
                YEAR: 1993,
                IMGURL: 'assets/Images/1/img3.jpg',
                MATERIAL: 'Collage auf Leinwand',
                SIZE: '14.2cm x 22.4cm',
                SERIE: 'BG-SWIPER'
     },
....
];
```

from Interface:

```
export interface Image {
    ID: number;
    NAME: string;
    YEAR: number;
    IMGURL: string;
    MATERIAL: string;
    SIZE: string;
    SERIE: string;
}
```

I have a gallery which shows the Images from a specific SERIES:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div *ngFor="let img of Katalog | keyValueFilter:{SERIE: 'BG-SWIPER' }">
                <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                    <a class="plate" [routerLink]="['/Werk', img.ID]" routerLinkActive="active-link">
                        <div class="bg-white shadow-sm">
                            <img [src]="img.IMGURL" class="img-fluid card-img-top">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With this KeyValue-Filter Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'keyValueFilter',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], filter: Record<string, any>): any {
    if (!items || !filter) {
      return items;
    }
    
    const key = Object.keys(filter)[0];
    const value = filter[key];

    return items.filter((e) => e[key].indexOf(value) !== -1);
  }
}
```

The example works when i hardcode the value of SERIE which goes through the Pipe and shows the corresponding images however i obviously don't want to create an individual galleryview for every series.

I tried this:

```
keyValueFilter:{SERIE: '{{img.SERIE}}' }">
```

but i get blankpage no errors in the console just empty objects:

```
<bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
```

The Filter accepts a string but i want to pass the current objects property {{img.SERIE}} to the pipe. Is there a way to stringify the objects value of a specific key or make something like a `ngIf* SERIE === {{img.SERIE}}?`

Comment: I'm not prety sure but I think should be`<... | keyValueFilter:{SERIE:gallery.SERIE}">` -see that you can not use the same name of the variable in *ngFor and in the pipe-

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve this by getting the SERIE string from the URL with:

```
serie = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('SERIE');
```

not using a pipe but instead:

```
<div *ngIf="img.SERIE === serie">
```

adding this to Router:

```
{ path: 'Serien/:SERIE', component: SerienAnsichtComponent, data: { preload: true }  },
```